# Emberjs. How to grab clicked related data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Am new in emberjs and I am trying to copy a practice using solely jquery. I cannot seem to able to do it. Maybe I should approche the following in a different way?

I have a view:

```
{{#each clip}}
    <div class="large-3 columns">
       <div {{action panel_clicked uuid}} class="panel" style="overflow:hidden; height:200px;">
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="notes" type='hidden'}}
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="uuid" type='hidden'}}
            {{{chunk}}}
        </div>
     </div>
 {{/each}}
```

What I want to do is when I click on the `class='panel'` I get the `uuid` and use that to get the hidden text fields.

Usually I will just have a custom id for the hidden field such as `id='notes_[uuid]'` so in jquery I can just do something like `$('#notes_' + uuid).val()` However I haven't figure out a way to generate a dynamic id in the `Ember.TextField`.

So is there a way to dynamically generate id in `Ember.TextField` or I should think bout it differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass in the object to the action.

```
{{#each clip}}
  <div {{action panel_clicked this on="click"}} class"panel">
  ...
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Where `this` refers to the current object in the each loop.

Then your action would just take the object as a parameter:

```
panel_clicked: function(clip) {
  alert(clip.get('someAttr')); // just to show it works
  ... // what you want to do
}
```

Check out the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on a view will generate a ['click' event on that view](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/). The `event.context` will be the model bound to that view.

```
App.ActionPanelView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(evt) {
    var model = evt.context;
    ....
  }
});

{{#each clip}}
    {{view App.ActionPanelView valueBinding=clip}}
{{/each}}
```

Ember should maintain all the bindings. If you ever find yourself

Comment: This is also a great answer! Thanks just I can tick one and spullen's ment lest change for my current code.